# How can I prevent idle sleep in a long-running bash script on Mac OS?

Tags: bash, macos, sleep-mode

I have a bash script that executes several long-running commands on Mac OS. How can I prevent the computer from going to sleep while the script is running?

Answer (score 20):

I found that I can achieve the desired behavior by adding this line to the start of the script:

```
caffeinate -i -w $$ &
```

How it works:

- [`caffeinate`](https://ss64.com/osx/caffeinate.html) is a built-in Mac OS utility for creating power management assertions to prevent sleep.

  - The `-i` flag tells `caffeinate` to prevent idle sleep.
  - The `-w` flag tells `caffeinate` to wait until the specified process finishes.
  - `$$` is a shell variable containing the current PID. Together with the `-w` flag this tells `caffeinate` to prevent sleep for the duration of the shell script.
- The final `&` runs the command in the background so the script can continue running.

Comment: `-i` is superfluous because it's already the default.